# Reading XML into Windows Form using XMLTextReader

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--This is an XML Generated File-->
<Subjects>
  <Subject>
    <Name>CG</Name>
    <TotalLectures>25</TotalLectures>
    <AttendedLectures>20</AttendedLectures>
  </Subject>
  <Subject>
    <Name>ISM</Name>
    <TotalLectures>40</TotalLectures>
    <AttendedLectures>37</AttendedLectures>
  </Subject>
</Subjects>
```

I need to read these elements (Name, TotalLectures, AttendedLectures) and display them in 3 separate textboxes. But I'm unable to achieve the result.

I'm using XMLTextReader, since Linq to XML, XPath and others seemed a little complicated.

This is the closest I could get (using help from another question on StackOverflow):

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("xmldata.xml");
                reader.Read();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.Name == "Name")
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = reader.ReadString();
                    }
                    if (reader.Name == "TotalLectures")
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = reader.ReadString();
                    }
                    if (reader.Name == "AttendedLectures")
                    {
                        textBox3.Text = reader.ReadString();
                    }
                }
```

But this is not displaying the details of the subject properly. I really need to get this working for my project! :S

Comment: There are two subjects in the XML, means there are 6 detail elements to display. How do you want them to be displayed in 3 TextBoxes?

Comment: I need to display one subject details at a time. There could be 8-9 subjects in the XML file, but the Winform displays only one (which is chosen by the user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed when user select a Subject, subject id stored in a variable say it `SubjectId`. Then you can do the following using XDocument with LINQ :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("xmldata.xml");
var subjectNode = doc.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault(o => o.Value == SubjectId).Parent;
textBox1.Text = subjectNode.Element("Name").Value;
textBox2.Text = subjectNode.Element("TotalLectures").Value;
textBox3.Text = subjectNode.Element("AttendedLectures").Value;
```

- `doc.Descendants("Name")` will return all element with tag "Name", then
- `.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Value == SubjectId)` will filter previous result to return only the first element having `Value` equal `SubjectId`, or return null if no matched element found, then
- `.Parent` will return parent element -*Subject tag in this case*- of previous result element -*Name tag*-. So `subjectNode` will contain Subject tag of user selected subject.

Comment: This is brilliant! I hope I can get a hold of Linq now. This looks so so simple. Thanks!(y)

Comment: If I wish to update any existing element, then how could I do it? Can I change the above code as subjectNode.Element("TotalLectures").Value = 50; ? Will this work?

Comment: @Rajat Yes that will, if you [save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) back `doc` to xml file at the end of modification : `doc.Save("xmldata.xml");`

Comment: Yes I managed to do that. I completed my application! Thank you so much!